# Lenovo screen flickering/Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, screen

After one hour of work my screen started suddenly flickering as if huge vertical stripe swipes fast.

Here what I have:

- Intel® Core™ i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz × 8
- GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

What are your suggestions of fixing it?

*Seems that with time this motion became more smooth*

Comment: Have you install an Nvidia driver? Check with `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.

Comment: @mikewhatever yes, **ii  nvidia-361 367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1  amd64 Transitional package for nvidia-367**...

Comment: Might want to try a newer one, nvidia-375, which should also be available in Additional Drivers.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanx

Comment: Like mike said your card is not in the supported list of that driver http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/108586/en-us ; go with the newer one. Which is the 375 which has your card in it's supported list http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/118290/en-us

Comment: That's a typical hardware issue that appears with older flat screens. Hardware issues are off topic here.